# Android Nested Fragments with a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a project (https://github.com/checklist/NestedFragmentsRecycler) with nested fragments. FragmentA is in the MainActivity and contains RecyclerView with an adapter. Each of the items in the adapter will have in return FragmentB. Since I need to give an id for loading FragmentB into position and it needs to be unique, I am generating my own ids. The first fragments are shown fine but unfortunately, the moment I start scrolling, I get an exception that my unique id cannot be found:

> W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource
>   number 0x00000004 E/FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x4
>   (unknown) for fragment FragmentB{30cad9b #3 id=0x4} E/FragmentManager:
>   Activity state: D/FragmentManager:   Local FragmentActivity 6d29cb6
>   State: D/FragmentManager:     mCreated=truemResumed=true
>   mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false D/FragmentManager:
>   mLoadersStarted=true D/FragmentManager:   Active Fragments in a2d5538:
>   D/FragmentManager:     #0: FragmentA{6948911 #0 id=0x7f0b0056}
>   D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentId=#7f0b0056 mContainerId=#7f0b0056
>   mTag=null D/FragmentManager:       mState=5 mIndex=0
>   mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0 D/FragmentManager:
>   mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
>   D/FragmentManager:       mHidden=false mDetached=false
>   mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false D/FragmentManager:
>   mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
>   D/FragmentManager:       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{a2d5538 in
>   HostCallbacks{327ba76}} D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:       mArguments=Bundle[{}] D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{ffe8877 V.E...... ........
>   128,32-2432,1496 #7f0b0056 app:id/fragmentA} D/FragmentManager:
>   mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{ffe8ce4 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-2304,1464} D/FragmentManager:
>   mInnerView=android.widget.LinearLayout{ffe8ce4 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-2304,1464} D/FragmentManager:       Child FragmentManager{aa7a54d
>   in FragmentA{6948911}}: D/FragmentManager:         Active Fragments in
>   aa7a54d: D/FragmentManager:           #0: FragmentB{44d0802 #0 id=0x1}
>   D/FragmentManager:             mFragmentId=#1 mContainerId=#1
>   mTag=null D/FragmentManager:             mState=5 mIndex=0
>   mWho=android:fragment:0:0 mBackStackNesting=0 D/FragmentManager:
>   mAdded=true mRemoving=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
>   D/FragmentManager:             mHidden=false mDetached=false
>   mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false D/FragmentManager:
>   mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{aa7a54d in FragmentA{6948911}}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:             mParentFragment=FragmentA{6948911 #0
>   id=0x7f0b0056} D/FragmentManager:
>   mArguments=Bundle[{TEXT=This is Fragment B:0}] D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{c93513 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464 #1} D/FragmentManager:
>   mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{3899350 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464} D/FragmentManager:
>   mInnerView=android.widget.LinearLayout{3899350 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464} D/FragmentManager:             Child
>   FragmentManager{c564949 in FragmentB{44d0802}}: D/FragmentManager:
>   FragmentManager misc state: D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1@287a24e
>   D/FragmentManager:                 mParent=FragmentB{44d0802 #0
>   id=0x1} D/FragmentManager:                 mCurState=5
>   mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false D/FragmentManager:           #1:
>   FragmentB{d880f6f #1 id=0x2} D/FragmentManager:
>   mFragmentId=#2 mContainerId=#2 mTag=null D/FragmentManager:
>   mState=5 mIndex=1 mWho=android:fragment:0:1 mBackStackNesting=0
>   D/FragmentManager:             mAdded=true mRemoving=false
>   mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false D/FragmentManager:
>   mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
>   D/FragmentManager:             mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false
>   mUserVisibleHint=true D/FragmentManager:
>   mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{aa7a54d in FragmentA{6948911}}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:             mParentFragment=FragmentA{6948911 #0
>   id=0x7f0b0056} D/FragmentManager:
>   mArguments=Bundle[{TEXT=This is Fragment B:1}] D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{67c947c V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464 #2} D/FragmentManager:
>   mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{c313105 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464} D/FragmentManager:
>   mInnerView=android.widget.LinearLayout{c313105 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464} D/FragmentManager:             Child
>   FragmentManager{cbf955a in FragmentB{d880f6f}}: D/FragmentManager:
>   FragmentManager misc state: D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1@ab0338b
>   D/FragmentManager:                 mParent=FragmentB{d880f6f #1
>   id=0x2} D/FragmentManager:                 mCurState=5
>   mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false D/FragmentManager:           #2:
>   FragmentB{53c7c68 #2 id=0x3} D/FragmentManager:
>   mFragmentId=#3 mContainerId=#3 mTag=null D/FragmentManager:
>   mState=5 mIndex=2 mWho=android:fragment:0:2 mBackStackNesting=0
>   D/FragmentManager:             mAdded=true mRemoving=false
>   mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false D/FragmentManager:
>   mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
>   D/FragmentManager:             mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false
>   mUserVisibleHint=true D/FragmentManager:
>   mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{aa7a54d in FragmentA{6948911}}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:             mParentFragment=FragmentA{6948911 #0
>   id=0x7f0b0056} D/FragmentManager:
>   mArguments=Bundle[{TEXT=This is Fragment B:2}] D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.widget.FrameLayout{918d881 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464 #3} D/FragmentManager:
>   mView=android.widget.LinearLayout{651ad26 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464} D/FragmentManager:
>   mInnerView=android.widget.LinearLayout{651ad26 V.E...... ........
>   0,0-800,1464} D/FragmentManager:             Child
>   FragmentManager{4ec7d67 in FragmentB{53c7c68}}: D/FragmentManager:
>   FragmentManager misc state: D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1@b90f714
>   D/FragmentManager:                 mParent=FragmentB{53c7c68 #2
>   id=0x3} D/FragmentManager:                 mCurState=5
>   mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false D/FragmentManager:           #3:
>   FragmentB{30cad9b #3 id=0x4} D/FragmentManager:
>   mFragmentId=#4 mContainerId=#4 mTag=null D/FragmentManager:
>   mState=1 mIndex=3 mWho=android:fragment:0:3 mBackStackNesting=0
>   D/FragmentManager:             mAdded=true mRemoving=false
>   mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false D/FragmentManager:
>   mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
>   D/FragmentManager:             mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false
>   mUserVisibleHint=true D/FragmentManager:
>   mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{aa7a54d in FragmentA{6948911}}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:             mParentFragment=FragmentA{6948911 #0
>   id=0x7f0b0056} D/FragmentManager:
>   mArguments=Bundle[{TEXT=This is Fragment B:3}] D/FragmentManager:
>   Added Fragments: D/FragmentManager:           #0: FragmentB{44d0802 #0
>   id=0x1} D/FragmentManager:           #1: FragmentB{d880f6f #1 id=0x2}
>   D/FragmentManager:           #2: FragmentB{53c7c68 #2 id=0x3}
>   D/FragmentManager:           #3: FragmentB{30cad9b #3 id=0x4}
>   D/FragmentManager:         FragmentManager misc state:
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.support.v4.app.Fragment$1@5797bbd
>   D/FragmentManager:           mParent=FragmentA{6948911 #0
>   id=0x7f0b0056} D/FragmentManager:           mCurState=5
>   mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false D/FragmentManager:   Added
>   Fragments: D/FragmentManager:     #0: FragmentA{6948911 #0
>   id=0x7f0b0056} D/FragmentManager:   FragmentManager misc state:
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mHost=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks@327ba76
>   D/FragmentManager:     mCurState=5 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
>   I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=27KB I/art:
>   After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=27KB I/art: Increasing
>   code cache capacity to 128KB D/FragmentManager:   View Hierarchy:
>   D/FragmentManager:     com.android.internal.policy.DecorView{99b75b2
>   V.E..... ... 0,0-2560,1800} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{eb98903 V.E..... ... 0,0-2560,1704}
>   D/FragmentManager:         android.view.ViewStub{8107080 G.E..... ...
>   0,0-0,0 #10203ef android:id/action_mode_bar_stub} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.FrameLayout{44716b9 V.E..... ... 0,48-2560,1704}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{7473afe V.E..... ...
>   0,0-2560,1656 #7f0b0044 app:id/decor_content_parent}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout{bc1b25f V.E..... ...
>   0,128-2560,1656 #1020002 android:id/content} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout{a4c14ac V.E..... ... 0,0-2560,1528
>
> ## 7f0b0055 app:id/activity_main} D/FragmentManager:                 android.widget.FrameLayout{ffe8877 V.E..... ... 128,32-2432,1496
>
> ## 7f0b0056 app:id/fragmentA} D/FragmentManager:                   android.widget.LinearLayout{ffe8ce4 V.E..... ... 0,0-2304,1464}
>
> D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{9b96575 VFEDH... F..
>   0,0-2304,1464 #7f0b0057 app:id/listView} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{e58090a V.E..... ... -19,0-781,1464}
>   W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource
>   number 0x00000001 D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.FrameLayout{c93513 V.E..... ... 0,0-800,1464 #1}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{3899350 V.E..... ... 0,0-800,1464}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{5f9157b V.ED.... ...
>   0,0-254,38 #7f0b0070 app:id/textView} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{7bbcf98 V.E..... ... 781,0-1581,1464}
>   W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource
>   number 0x00000002 D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.FrameLayout{67c947c V.E..... ... 0,0-800,1464 #2}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{c313105 V.E..... ... 0,0-800,1464}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{bc7e3f1 V.ED.... ...
>   0,0-254,38 #7f0b0070 app:id/textView} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{8f5abd6 V.E..... ... 1581,0-2381,1464}
>   W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting name for resource
>   number 0x00000003 D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.FrameLayout{918d881 V.E..... ... 0,0-800,1464 #3}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.widget.LinearLayout{651ad26 V.E..... ... 0,0-800,1464}
>   D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{8798e57 V.ED.... ...
>   0,0-254,38 #7f0b0070 app:id/textView} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer{36a4d44 V.ED.... ...
>   0,0-2560,128 #7f0b0045 app:id/action_bar_container} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar{e65ce2d V.E..... ... 0,0-2560,128
>
> ## 7f0b0046 app:id/action_bar} D/FragmentManager:                 android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{9f8af62 V.ED.... ...
>
> 48,37-153,91} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView{c1eb8f3 V.E..... ...
>   2544,0-2544,128} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView{460f9b0 G.E..... ...
>   0,0-0,0 #7f0b0047 app:id/action_context_bar} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.view.View{77e2029 V.ED.... ... 0,1704-2560,1800 #1020030
>   android:id/navigationBarBackground} D/FragmentManager:
>   android.view.View{7365fae V.ED.... ... 0,0-2560,48 #102002f
>   android:id/statusBarBackground} D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: example.com.demo, PID: 8156
>                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x4 (unknown) for fragment FragmentB{30cad9b #3 id=0x4}
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1107)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1295)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1682)
>                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:541)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8616', transport:
>   'socket'

The 2 main classes are FragmentAAdapter and FragmentB (you can see the other classes if you need, in the git repo):

```
public class FragmentAAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

FragmentA fragmentA;
Activity activity;
RecyclerView listView;

public FragmentAAdapter(FragmentA fragmentA, Activity activity, RecyclerView listView) {
    this.fragmentA = fragmentA;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listView = listView;
}


@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, parent, false);
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = new BoardViewHolder(v, this);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof BoardViewHolder){
        BoardViewHolder pHolder = (BoardViewHolder)holder;
        pHolder.onBindViewHolder(position);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 10;
}

public class BoardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    FragmentAAdapter adapter;
    FragmentB fragmentB;
    View view;

    public BoardViewHolder(View itemView, FragmentAAdapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);

        this.view = itemView;
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(int position) {

        FragmentManager fm = fragmentA.getChildFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentB==null) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("TEXT", "This is Fragment B:" + position);
            fragmentB = FragmentB.getInstance(bundle);

            int boardId = generateViewId();
            // switch the id of the board to be unique
            View board = view.findViewById(R.id.board);
            board.setId(boardId);

            // now flip fragmentB
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(boardId, fragmentB);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}

private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);

public static int generateViewId() {
    for (;;) {
        final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
        // aapt-generated IDs have the high byte nonzero; clamp to the range under that.
        int newValue = result + 1;
        if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1; // Roll over to 1, not 0.
        if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

}

and FragmentB:

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

View root;

Activity activity;

String text;
private TextView textView;

public static FragmentB getInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    FragmentB instance = new FragmentB();
    instance.setArguments(bundle);
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    activity = (Activity) getActivity();

    if (getArguments()!=null) {
        text = getArguments().getString("TEXT");

    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false);

    textView = (TextView)root.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(text);

    return root;
}
```

}

Full code: https://github.com/checklist/NestedFragmentsRecycler

Thanks!

Comment: generate new IDs inside `onCreateViewHolder`, not `onBindViewHolder`: you only need as many IDs as many holders / views you have

Comment: already tried that and get the same exception

Comment: before any scrolling, what is the output of the command: `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: BTW - I get this exception on tablet/phone client (api v25). On api 19 it does not crash as often. Just a hint. This is the dump: https://github.com/checklist/NestedFragmentsRecycler/blob/master/log.txt

Comment: ok, instead of generating Ids, setting them to views, creating fragments by hand and using `FragmentTransaction#replace` why dont you simply use `<fragment ...` tag in your item layout xml?

Comment: This could work but not sure how to do it. Can you show me an example? Mostly, I am not sure how to init FragmentB with a bundle. Also, I seem to get a duplicate id exception.

Comment: see: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127542/discussion-between-checklist-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of soul searching, I can confirm that it is not possible to generate IDs inside fragments. IF you do so, Android gets confused while rendering the UI and the app crashes.

I have tried this in another project where we generated ids for radio buttons and groups that were dynamically generated and placed within a fragment and same behavior. Two solutions:
- do not create programatically so you don't need to generate ids
- do not use fragments